# How to click on first li element programmatically using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a list of li elements inside ul

```
<ul>
   <li><a href=#>ABC</a></li>
   <li><a href=#>DEF</a></li>
   <li><a href=#>GHI</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do i programmatically click first element of li and call a JS function on that click. i.e. i want the li element to be clicked when the page loads

Comment: do you want to click the first `li` element or click the Link `a` inside the first li-Element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select first `li` using [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector and use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to fire click event for it.

```
$("ul li:first").trigger("click");
```

```js
$("ul li:first").click(function(){
  console.log("First li clicked");
});
$("ul li:first").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><a href=#>ABC</a></li>
   <li><a href=#>DEF</a></li>
   <li><a href=#>GHI</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function clickAlert(){
alert("I am called");
}

$('ul li:first').trigger('click',clickAlert());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><a href=#>ABC</a></li>
   <li><a href=#>DEF</a></li>
   <li><a href=#>GHI</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has ways for declaring event handlers and triggering them.

Select the first `<li>` element with `$('ul li:first')`

```
$('ul li:first').click(function() {
    // This will handle the click event
    // Put your JS function here.
});

$('ul li:first').click(); // This triggers the click event
$('ul li:first').trigger('click') // Will also trigger click event
```